# Issue with scraping data with foreign characters

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, web-scraping

I have written a python script to scrape data from some chinese site. According to its head charset is "gb2312" and have also checked it with "chardet.detect()" python library that its correct but still i get wrong characters. Here is my code:

```
import csv
import requests
import cssselect
from lxml import html

url = "http://www.example.com/"
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36'}

mainPage = requests.get(url, headers = header)
tree = html.fromstring(mainPage.content)

with open('jd(test).csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    main_info = ["URL", "CAT-Name Original", "CAT-Name Converted"]
    csvwriter.writerow(main_info)

    for link in tree.cssselect("div#allsort div div.m div.mc dl dd em a"):
        urls = [link.get('href')]
        text = link.text

        print (urls)

        convertedText = text.encode('gb2312')

        print (text)
        print (convertedText)

        row_info = [urls, text, convertedText]

        csvwriter.writerow(row_info)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['http://example.com/']
戏曲综艺
b'\xcf\xb7\xc7\xfa\xd7\xdb\xd2\xd5'
```

Comment: @lserni "Opera Arts" as convertedText

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand. `convertedText` is a bytearray (in GB2312 encoding) and is correct. `print '\xcf\xb7\xc7\xfa\xd7\xdb\xd2\xd5'.decode('gb2312')` gives me 戏曲综艺, which is Opera Arts (according to Google Translate at least).

Comment: @lserni But I need "Opera Arts" instead of b'\xcf\xb7\xc7\xfa\xd7\xdb\xd2\xd5'. I know to use google and bing api but that's not free.

Comment: Sorry, but do you mean that you want it *translated into English*? That's not what encode does.

Comment: okay I got it but what do i need to do to get it translated without using any thrid party?

Comment: What if i want 戏曲综艺 in my csv instead of 'ç”µå­ä¹¦'

Comment: You write `text` to the CSV instead of `convertedText`. Remember, you will then need to read the CSV using a UTF8-aware application.

Comment: @lserni thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask cannot work; encoding is for character sets only, you want **translation**.

You can get it using [py-translate](http://pythonhosted.org/py-translate/devs/api.html#translator-co-routine), which is an interface to Google but apparently free to use.

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Mar 27 2015, 02:30:53) [GCC] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from translate import translator
>>> translator('zh-Tw', 'en', '戏曲综艺')
[[['Opera Arts', '戏曲综艺', 0]], 'zh-TW']
>>>
```

I am not wholly familiar with the tool, so you'll better check out the license.

> what do i need to do to get it translated without using any third party?

By definition, if you do not want to use *any third party*, your only option is to *learn Chinese*. In some outfits that might be a workable option. <sup><sup>Case in point: a firm I worked for needed some Chinese translations. Then more. And more. First they hired a translator. Then a Chinese intern, and organized a Chinese course for two developers. Depending on the amount of data, it could be economically convenient.</sup></sup>

But I think you want some kind of *free (as in beer) tool*. The problem being that most tools are either quite amateurish and will at best spew [Engrish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engrish), or are **not free** in some form or other; they might be trials, or "personal use". The fact is that people developing these tools need to put in *a lot of work*, and they understandably seek some sort of return on their investment. You should at least ask yourself, *what should I give back?*, and, *what am I giving back (knowingly or not)?*. Unfortunately - until a post-scarcity singularity -  this applies to *everything*.

You can try e.g. the [Baidu service](http://translate.baidu.com/) that has no "reasonable or personal use" limit that I can readily see, but has his ideas on your privacy ("Baidu hereby reminds users that the content you input into Baidu Translate *will not be considered as your private personal information*."). As long as you do not translate anything... *controversial*... there should be no problems.